# Setting the httponly property to false in a cookie

Tags: php, laravel

How would i using Laravel make a cookie using `Cookie::Make` (Or something else) and set the httponly property to false?

I would want to do this as the cookie contains a key which my JS must be able to read.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Laravel provides an option for this, but the docs don't show it. The best way is to look through the source. If you take a look at the CookieJar.php file [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Cookie/CookieJar.php) you'll see the httpOnly option.

```
public function make($name, $value, $minutes = 0, $path = null, $domain = null, $secure = false, $httpOnly = true)
```

so simply do something like:

```
Cookie::make('MyCookie', 'MyValue', 60, null, null, false, false);
```

Comment: Your answer was invaluable and helpful for me. Thanks you :)