# Javascript not reading cookies set by Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, cookies, laravel-5

Javascript not reading cookies set by Laravel in the same domain and returning `undefined`.
It's only reading the XSRF-Token but not any other cookies whether be it encrypted or unencrypted.

The URL is: `http://localhost:8000/myaccount`

and here is the cookie screenshot

[image]

I'm using JS Cookie library .. It's not reading either using `document.cookie` or `Cookies.get('user_id')` only the XSRF-TOKEN is reading.

Answer (score 1):

Cookie `user-id` has `http-only` flag set to `true`. 
It is not therefore accessible by javascript.

Try and set `http-only` flag to `false`.

edit: check [this other SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21510810/setting-the-httponly-property-to-false-in-a-cookie) it might get you started

Answer (score 1):

The cookie is HttpOnly, therefore cannot be read by Javascript. You have to set the cookie as `$httpOnly = false`

See the last parameter of [CookieJar::make method](https://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Cookie/CookieJar.html#method_make) - which is mirrored in facade Cookie::make method.